# Can't get Calendar to work with Redux Forms

Tags: redux-form

Trying to get [Calendar](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets) to work with a [Redux Form](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/react-widgets/)

Using a Redux Form Field:

```
<Field name={name} component={this.renderCal}/>
```

which is leveraging a stateless function:

```
renderCal({input, ...rest}) {
    input.value = new Date();
    return <Calendar {...input}
                     onChange={() => input.onChange(input.value)}
                     value={input.value}
                     {...rest}/>
}
```

When I submit the form, the value is still null. I appears like the value is not bound to the component. This is my request payload from the Chrome Developer Tools > Network ...

```
inputs : [{name: "fromDate", title: "From Date", dataType: "date", format: "mm/dd/yyyy", value: null}] 0 : {name: "fromDate", title: "From Date", dataType: "date", format: "mm/dd/yyyy", value: null} dataType : "date" format : "mm/dd/yyyy" name : "fromDate" title : "From Date" value : null
```

Does anyone have Calendar working with Redux Form as a stateless function?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Steve and I found a solution. Posting back our findings for everyone else...

To clarify, the initial state/shape of the form is actually an array of dates:

```
{
 myDates: [
  {myDate: null},
  {myDate: null},
  {myDate: null}
 ]
}
```

If you just need to tie DateTimePicker up to a Redux Form field then you can drop *renderDynamicField**s*** and use *renderDynamicField* directly:

```
<Field name={name} component={renderDynamicField}/>
```

**Points of Note:**

1. Changed directions slightly and are now using [DateTimePicker](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/datetime-picker?_k=1eg293) as opposed to Calendar because we also needed the time portion. That being said the solution should work with Calendar too.
2. Used Redux Form FieldArray
3. DateTimePicker needed a "defaultValue"

**Solution**

```
import React from "react";
import {Button, Col, Form, FormGroup, ControlLabel} from "react-bootstrap";
import {reduxForm, Field, FieldArray} from "redux-form";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {DateTimePicker} from "react-widgets";
class ReactWidgets extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderDynamicFields = this.renderDynamicFields.bind(this);
    }

    submit(form) {
        console.log('form', form);
    }

    renderDynamicFields({fields = []}) {

        let collection = [];
        fields.map((name, index) => {
            collection.push(<Field key={index} name={`${name}.myDate`} component={renderDynamicField}/>);
        });
        return <div>{collection}</div>;

        function renderDynamicField(props) {
            const {input} = props;
            let component = null;
            if (true) { // going to support different types...
                component = <DateTimePicker
                    defaultValue={input.value || new Date()}
                    onChange={(value) => {
                        input.onChange(value);
                    }}/>;
            }
            return component;
        }
    }


    render() {

        const {error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;

        return (
            <Form horizontal onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
                <FormGroup><Col componentClass={ControlLabel} xs={2}>
                    My Date2</Col>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <FieldArray name="myDates" component={this.renderDynamicFields}/>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={1} xs={11}>
                        <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary"
                                disabled={pristine || submitting}>Save</Button>&nbsp;
                        <Button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                onClick={reset}>Reset</Button>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

ReactWidgets = reduxForm({
    form: 'reactWidgets'
})(ReactWidgets);

ReactWidgets = connect(
    state => {
        return {
            initialValues: {
                myDates: [
                    {myDate: null},
                    {myDate: null},
                    {myDate: null}
                ]
            },
        }
    })(ReactWidgets)

export default ReactWidgets
```